# Filtrar datos desde un ListView personalizado

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando un aplicación, en la cual en un `ListView` personalizado muestro 3 valores, los cuales obtengo de un `ArrayList`.

El problema es que los tres valores están organizados horizontalmente. En el valor de la izquierda esta el nombre, y en el valor del centro y de la derecha están otros valores numéricos.

Lo que quiero es poder filtrar por el nombre en el `EditText` que tengo en la parte superior.

El código es el siguiente:

Así es como obtengo los datos en la clase principal y los envío al adaptador para organizarlos:

```
ArrayList<Elementos> elementos1 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j <= lista.size()/3; j++) {

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i+=3) {
        elementos = new Elementos("","","");
        elementos.setIzquierda(lista.get(i));
        elementos.setCentro(lista.get(i+1));
        elementos.setDerecha(lista.get(i+2));

        elementos1.add(j, elementos);
        j++;
    }
}

lvProductos.setAdapter(new Adaptador(getApplicationContext(), elementos1));
```

Así es como los organizo en el adaptador:

```
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);


    tvIzquierda = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tvCentro = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tvDerecha = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tv3);

    tvIzquierda.setText(ja.get(i).izquierda);
    tvCentro.setText(ja.get(i).centro);
    tvDerecha.setText(ja.get(i).derecha);


    return vista;
}
```

Si alguien sabe cómo podría filtrar únicamente por el nombre, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Yo haría el filtrado fuera del adapter. Le pasaría el `arrayList` de `Elementos` filtrados y llamaría a `notifyDataSetChanged` para que repintara todo el adapter con los nuevos `Elementos`.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer el filtrado, primero deberíamos crear una variable de tu adapter e instanciarlo. Puedes instanciarlo si estas utilizando un fragment en el `onViewCreated()` o si estas utilizando un Activity en el `onCreate()` ( Asumiendo que toda la lógica que realizas con tus vistas y variables son en estos métodos.

Instanciamos el adaptar. en alguno de los dos métodos descritos, de momento le pasamos un arreglo vacío.

```
Adaptador adapter = new Adaptador(getApplicationContext(), new ArrayList<>())
```

Ahora en tu método donde aplicas el filtrado seria lo siguiente:

```
public void filtrar(String texto){
    ArrayList<Elementos> filtrarlista = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i+=3) {// Esta es tu lista desde donde quieres faltar
        if (list[i].getIzquierda().toLowerCase().contains(texto.toLowerCase())) {
            filtrarlista.add(list[i]);
        }
    }
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(filtrarlista);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

}
```

la variable `String texto` es el texto de tu edittext que quieres filtrar.

Espero te ayude :)